# Is Light Amplification Synchronise Electron/Positron Radiation possible?

Tags: laser, antimatter

Light Amplification Stimulated by Emission of Radiation vs Light Amplification by Sychronised Electron/Positron Radiation

By applying a "custom" undulator(a series of powerful magnets) to break up random free electrons into small bunches like the one used in Free Electron Laser, then insert bunches of positrons in between the bunches of electrons also at relativistic speed. 
Ignore engineering issues for now, is this matter-antimatter beam in theory feasible?

Comment: Not sure, what you're hoping to achieve with this. Coherent emission might work, except your electrons and positrons will turn in different directions at the nearest bending magnet. If you're talking annihilation, then nope, 0.5MeV quanta have much shorter wavelengths than electron bunches.

Comment: If the electrons and positrons are moving at high energies and the stimulating photon is directed opposite to that motion, then the photon wavelength can be much larger.  See the link to Rivlin's paper in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was proposed and explored in a paper by Rivlin in 1978.  Here is a link to the paper's abstract: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/QE1978v008n11ABEH011340